# Multiple constructors for same configuration should create only one instance

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a few classes defined : 
Food
Bread
Butter
FoodFactory

as follows :

Food.java

```
public abstract class Food {
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public abstract void eat();

    public Food(String id) {
        this.id = id;

        FoodFactory.getInstance().foodWasConstructed(this);
    }
}
```

FoodFactory.java

```
public class FoodFactory {
    private Map<String, Food> map = new HashMap<String, Food>();
    private static FoodFactory factory = new FoodFactory();

    private FoodFactory() {
    }

    public static FoodFactory getInstance() {
        return factory;
    }

    public synchronized Food getFood(String id, String type) {
        if(map.get(id) != null) {
            return map.get(id);
        } else {
            if(type.equals("bread")) {
                Food food = new Bread(id);
                map.put(id, food);
                return food;
            } else if(type.equals("butter")) {
                Food food = new Butter(id);
                map.put(id, food);
                return food;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void foodWasConstructed(Food food) {
        if(!map.containsKey(food.getId()))
            this.map.put(food.getId(), food);
    }
}
```

Bread.java

```
public class Bread extends Food {
    static int i;
    public Bread(String id) {
        super(id);
        i++;
    }

    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Eating bread : " + i);
    }
}
```

Butter.java

```
public class Butter extends Food {

    public Butter(String id) {
        super(id);
    }

    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Eating butter");
    }

}
```

Now my requirement is that I cannot create two Food instances with same id.
I try to run the below code :

```
public class SampleTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Food food1 = new Bread("1");
        Food food2 = new Bread("1");

        // food2 should return food1 reference. How can I accomplish this.
        // food2 creates entirely new instance. What I want is it should refer to food1 instance.
        // How can i do this. Is there any design flaw?
        FoodFactory.getInstance().getFood("1", "bread").eat();
    }
}
```

And get following output:

```
Eating bread : 2
```

My issue is as mentioned in comments : 
food2 should return food1 reference. How can I accomplish this.
food2 creates entirely new instance. What I want is it should refer to food1 instance. How can i do this. Is there any design flaw?

Comment: You can't do it with the `new` operator, this is what you use static factories for, like you already have in `FoodFactory`.

Comment: What about checking whether the key already exists into the map ? This seems reasonable to me. You also need to use static factory to get new instances of food.

Comment: @FabienThouraud It's already done in `FoodFactory` as far as I can tell.

Comment: @biziclop well ... I think I'm too tired right know ... sorry for this misreading.

Comment: @user3057107, can you try my answer.

Comment: If you want same reference every time. You should make that singleton.

Comment: You cannot make a constructor return an existing object... Once the constructor is called, there are only 2 options, either give a new object or throw an exception... For your case, make the constructor private in `Bread` and implement a static method similar to singleton, but return a distinct object for every unique ID passed.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to implement the `hashCode()` and `equals()` method for the `Food` class based on the variable `id`. Hence for every similar `id` passed to the constructor, only one class would be created. As `Bread` class extends `Food`, it gets the same behavior and creates only one class for the same `id`.

You can change your `Food` class to below

```
 public abstract class Food {
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public abstract void eat();

    public Food(String id) {
        this.id = id;

        FoodFactory.getInstance().foodWasConstructed(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Food other = (Food) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

---

SampleTest.java

```
<pre><code>public class SampleTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Food food1 = new Bread("1");
        Food food2 = new Bread("1");

        System.out.println(food1.hashCode());

        System.out.println(food2.hashCode());
        System.out.println(food1.equals(food2));

        // food2 should return food1 reference. How can I accomplish this.
        // food2 creates entirely new instance. What I want is it should refer
        // to food1 instance.
        // How can i do this. Is there any design flaw?
        FoodFactory.getInstance().getFood("1", "bread").eat();
    }
}</pre></code>
```

**Output**

```
  80
    80
    true
    Eating bread : 2
```

Comment: I think you didn't get my question..... in other words you can say , i am calling two constructors with same arguments but only one object is created in memory

Comment: Yes, did you try my implementation ?

Comment: food2 does refer to food1 now as the above output. Is this not what you wanted? Dude, just paste the above code for Food class, execute what you want and check if you are getting the desired output.

Comment: Eating bread : 2 should be Eating bread : 1.   Please read question carefully. Your equals method is just comparing the two different instances. Both have their memories in heap. I want food1 and food2 to refer to same heap location. Now you got my point?

Comment: How can you expect that ? the variable i in Bread is static and hence would be incremented every time the counter is called upon. When the constructor is invoked twice, the i would be 2 only but cannot be 1. i gets incremented when Food food1 = new Bread("1"); is executed and once more in getFood method in FoodFactory and hence you would get  2 , but never 1.

Answer (score -2):

Try changeing FoodFactory() constructor like this

```
public class FoodFactory {
    private Map<String, Food> map;
    private static FoodFactory factory;

    private FoodFactory() {
    }

    public static FoodFactory getInstance() {
if(factory==null)


{
factory = new FoodFactory();
map = new HashMap<String, Food>();

}
        return factory;
    }

}
```

It will always return same reference of FoodFactory instance.

Comment: The question is about `Food` not `FoodFactory`. And OPs code right now will only return same reference of `FoodFactory`.

Comment: Agreed with @Codebender : I want some code change in a way that food2 refers to food1 instance.

Comment: @user3057107 Make the class singleton

Comment: No..... there can be two or more different food instances with different ids say id = 1 , id = 2 etc. But only one instance with same id and that too using Food constructor. Its possible there is some design issues with my program

Comment: Why you are printing `i`, you sould print `id`. There is only one instance in map with same `id` if you change the `FoodFactory` class accrding to my answer.` public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Eating bread : " + getId());
    }`

Comment: @Varun : The printing purpose is to count no of instances and not id.

Comment: Ok. After editing `FoodFactory` you can debug and check that there is only on instance in the map.